# Syntax error when there's a newline after an or operator

Tags: python

This is OK:

```
if 'something' in data['meta']:
  <do something>
```

This is a syntax error. Why?

```
if ('something' in data['meta']) or
  ('something_else' in data['meta']):
    <do something>
```

The interpreter hands this out:

```
  File "test.py", line 1
    if ('something' in data['meta']) or
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Edit your question and add error string.

Comment: Maybe whitespace? There shouldn't be a new line after the or

Comment: don't break the line after the `or`, or put everything inside brakets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Newlines are important. Python needs to know how to parse things. For the second code snippet, you are separating the `if` into two lines, and Python doesn't like that since it looks like a separate command. Two common ways to span multiple lines is using a backslash or parentheses. For example, both of these are valid syntax:

```
if ('something' in data['meta']) or \
       ('something_else' in data['meta']):
    <do something>

if (('something' in data['meta']) or
       ('something_else' in data['meta'])):
    <do something>
```

You can read about this more in the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

**Small Note**: I add extra indentation on multi-line if statements to easily distinguish when the condition ends and when the subsequent code begins. It's just preference, and PEP8 provides options [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements).

Answer (score 4):

That is a syntax error because Python expects your `if` statement to end on that line, and with `:`.

However an expression such as this boolean one can continue to another line provided that you either

- you end the first line in backslash (`\`) character
- you wrap the expression in extra parentheses (preferred).

Thus, use either

```
if ('something' in data['meta']) or \
       ('something_else' in data['meta']):
    <do something>
```

or the preferred form

```
if (('something' in data['meta']) or
       ('something_else' in data['meta'])):
    <do something>
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The **preferred** way of wrapping long lines is by using **Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces.** Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

Answer (score 0):

breaking of line from "or" should be enclosed in brackets like:

```
if ('something' in data['meta'] or
    'something_else' in data['meta']):
    <do something>
```

Comment: The only difference is parenthesis over "in" condition, its is redundant. You don't need them.

Answer (score -1):

try code like this:

```
if ('something' in data['meta']) or ('something_else' in data['meta']):
    <do something>
```

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: He've answered himself.So I just give the right code

Comment: That may be true, **but he didn't ask for the right code**. He asked why he could not continue his or statement onto a newline